# UIAccelerometer reference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiaccelerometer

Can anybody suggest to me some good applications that make use of UIAccelerometer Class and some references too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BubbleLevel](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/BubbleLevel/index.html) is a sample app that's nice and simple, yet demonstrates the UIAccelerometer. First source of reference for the class is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html).

progmr suggests that you're looking for ideas for applications that can make use of the UIAccelerometer. BubbleLevel already hints at one major use of the accelerometer - that of knowing the orientation of the device.

The other major use is (obviously) tracking the acceleration of the phone, allowing for the interpretation of gestures, for instance: not just shaking, but gestures like you might use when playing a Wii game. This doesn't necessarily lend itself directly to knowing the velocity of the phone! (Integrating the acceleration gives you velocity + some constant factor unknowable without calibration.)

Comment: i want to develop an application myself.

Comment: He gave you exactly what you asked for and needed. A sample app (with code) and reference data. What more are you expecting?

Comment: Sounds like he's asking for ideas for new apps to develop.

Comment: You know, I didn't think of that interpretation at all. Oh well.